# вылетает FileNotFoundException (Permission denied). Как дать права intellij idea

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea, логирование, log4j

Когда хочу выводить логи в файл,и указываю такой путь к файлу:

```
log4j.debug=false

log4j.rootLogger=INFO, app

log4j.appender.app=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.app.file=${catalina.home}/logs/logs.log
log4j.appender.spring.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.spring.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.app.layout=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
log4j.appender.app.layout.conversionPattern=%d{DATE} [%-5p] [%-4L] [%-10.10t] [%25.25c] - %m%n
```

То получаю эту ошибку:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/tomcat/logs/logs.log (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:133)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)
    at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.setFile(RollingFileAppender.java:207)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:172)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:104)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:842)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:768)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:648)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:514)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:580)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:526)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.<init>(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:66)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<init>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:72)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:45)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:412)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:357)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:273)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4663)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5131)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:713)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:695)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1729)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:287)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:457)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:406)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:287)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1408)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Как это исправить?

Comment: Указать другой путь к файлу. Или дать нужные права указанной папке.

Comment: Как дать права нужной папке, только для intellij?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете дать всем права на папку `logs`, что решит проблему, при помощи команды:

```
sudo chmod 777 /opt/tomcat/logs
```

Однако это не лучшая практика. Лучше вести запись в папку, к которой уже есть права. К примеру можно создать некую папку в домашнем каталоге и писать логи туда, а в `log4.properties` прописать

```
log4j.appender.app.file=${user.home}/logs/logs.log
```

Ну или создать отдельную папку с логами и дать права на неё. В Linux принято писать логи в `/var/log`

```
sudo mkdir /var/log/tomcat-logs
sudo chown "${USER}" /var/log/tomcat-logs
```

И после использовать данную папку в `log4.properties`

```
log4j.appender.app.file=/var/log/tomcat-logs
```

Comment: Все понятно. Большое спасибо.